# Wordpress Website breaks in Google Chrome

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

This site I'm working on works perfectly fine in firefox and IE but in chrome it overlaps. I've been trying to figure out what the problem is can anyone help?

http://c2cdev.com/hocoa

could this be a css problem, I looked at the code over and over gain.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why.

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  .homepage-content {
    margin-top:125px;
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

It's rendering correctly.

```
media="screen"
.header-wrapper, .header-wrapper-inner {
background-color: #6da000;
background-image: url(images/pattern/transparent-grid3.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-position: top;
height: 504px;
}
```

The CSS says that the header is only `504px` tall. The `homepage-content` is rendering right after that which is **under** the header. You were then adding `125px` on the top margin which wasn't enough.

Comment: Remove that completely? Let's see

Comment: Removing it won't fix it.

Comment: I don't understand, do I need to modify anything? I messed with it but nothing is changing

Comment: I changed the margin-top but it remained the same

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your CSS. It's rendering correctly in Chrome. It's doing what you told it to do.